# Undefined control sequence in pspicture

Tags: pstricks, include

I tried to include an `*.eps` (saved as `*.tex` with another program)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
\include{t}
\end{document}
```

where `t.tex` is (shortened after the error line appears)

```
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(605.33331299,340){
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{1 1 1}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]{
\newpath
\moveto(302.61332577,0.0380208)
\lineto(0,0.0380208)
\lineto(0,339.9599915)
\lineto(605.1893182,339.9599915)
\lineto(605.1893182,0.0380208)
\lineto(302.61332577,0.0380208)
}}%ERROR LINE - ERROR LINE - ERROR LINE - ERROR LINE - ERROR LINE
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157}
\pscustom[linewidth=0.99999949,linecolor=curcolor]{
\newpath
\moveto(93.47018108,67.31197656)
\lineto(93.47018108,72.97811231)
}}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157}
\pscustom[linewidth=0.99999949,linecolor=curcolor]{
\newpath
\moveto(93.47018108,67.31197656)
\lineto(93.47018108,72.97811231)
}}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157}
\pscustom[linewidth=0.99999949,linecolor=curcolor]{
\newpath
\moveto(95.74005815,287.79562041)
\lineto(94.03738349,288.32458055)
\lineto(93.99989022,288.28594115)
\lineto(93.96186324,288.24863413)
\lineto(93.96186324,288.20999473)
\closepath
}}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0.00392157 0.00392157 0.00392157}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]{
\newpath
\moveto(96.42026426,97.00213091)
\lineto(96.42026426,97.11506424)
\lineto(96.38226426,97.15306424)
\lineto(96.38226426,97.3041309)
\lineto(96.34479759,97.3417309)
\lineto(96.34479759,97.3797309)
\lineto(96.30679759,97.41719756)
}}
\end{pspicture}
```

This is just a MWE, wondering wether including the file in my normal document will work when it works here.

Comment: Your MWE runs through when I compile it with `xelatex` on my TeXLive 2017 distribution. Of course, the picture is ultra tiny.

Comment: With `latex` instead of `pdflatex` (or `pdflatex -output-format dvi`) there is no error message. This produces a `.dvi` file, which you can convert to `pdf` with `dvips myfile.dvi` followed by `ps2pdf myfile.ps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
    \section{asdf}
    \input{t}
\end{document}
```

and run it with `xelatex` and use `\input` and not `\include`˛. However, your image is totally nonsense because it does more or less "nothing". Here is the output with \psframebox{\input{t}}:

[image]